# GWT Compilation Error - IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: gwt

When compiling the project, I get this obscure Exception

```
Looking for precompiled archives.  To disable, use -Dgwt.usearchives=false
Loading archived module: jar:file:<base>/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/User.gwtar
[WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:<base>/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/User.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3824090149180578568, local class serialVersionUID = -2622986784335128516
Loading archived module: jar:file:<base>/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/Core.gwtar
[WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:<base>/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/Core.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3824090149180578568, local class serialVersionUID = -2622986784335128516
Loading archived module: jar:file:<base>/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/regexp/RegExp.gwtar
[WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:<base>/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/regexp/RegExp.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3824090149180578568, local class serialVersionUID = -2622986784335128516
Loading archived module: jar:file:<base>/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar!/com/google/web/bindery/event/Event.gwtar
Loading archived module: jar:file:<base>/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/xml/XML.gwtar
[WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:<base>/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/xml/XML.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3824090149180578568, local class serialVersionUID = -2622986784335128516
Loading archived module: jar:file:<base>/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/json/JSON.gwtar
[WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:<base>/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/json/JSON.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3824090149180578568, local class serialVersionUID = -2622986784335128516
Found 0 cached/archived units.  Used 0 / 4578 units from cache.
Compiling...
  0% complete (ETR: 93 seconds)
  10% complete (ETR: 56 seconds)
  20% complete (ETR: 37 seconds)
  30% complete (ETR: 25 seconds)
  40% complete (ETR: 18 seconds)
  50% complete (ETR: 14 seconds)
  60% complete (ETR: 10 seconds)
  70% complete (ETR: 7 seconds)
  80% complete (ETR: 5 seconds)
  90% complete (ETR: 2 seconds)
  100% complete (ETR: 0 seconds)
  Compilation completed in 28.40 seconds
[ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker$CompileDependencyVisitor has interface com.google.gwt.dev.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.visitCompileDependenciesInBytecode(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:217)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.getCompileDependencySignature(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:199)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompiledClass.getSignatureHash(CompiledClass.java:152)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:42)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:37)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies.resolve(Dependencies.java:114)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:311)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:511)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:434)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:420)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:485)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:241)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:223)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:139)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:167)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:132)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:99)
at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:106)
Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
```

Where could I start looking for the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try it again after removing all the generated stub and re-compiling the project again.

I have highlighted all the stubs that needs to be deleted as shown in below snapshot.

[image]

Here is the list of folders (name can vary based on your GWT project compilation module name) that need to be removed.

- gwt-unitCache
- test-classes
- war > gwtproject
- war > WEB-INF > classes
- war > WEB-INF > deploy

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately exact same error. I could find all folders, except gwtproject.

Comment: After a couple of clean-build, your solution worked!

Comment: I think you have missed to remove auto generated javascript files that is in folder `gwtproject` in my case.

Comment: My Maven project does not contain that folder.

Comment: Hi @Braj, Your snapshot image is not visible. Can you write those as a content ?

Comment: @Jess updated the post... Please let me know if the issue is still not resolved.

Comment: Nope, this didnt resolve my issue. 
    `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.google.gwt.dev.javac.asm.CollectMethodData has interface com.google.gwt.dev.asm.MethodVisitor as super class`

Some how i feel, i messed up with GWT2.7 and GWT 2.6. As you mentioned, clearing up the stuffs should start all over again but am still getting the error. I ran with the default GWT 2.7. But for my project i needed only GWT 2.6.1.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had to remove the asm 3.1 from my classpath and there are few jars which has internal dependency on asm 3.1. Which i had to exclude from the dependency in my pom. example:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion> <!-- exclude version 3 of asm -->
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
          </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
```

There were other jars which has such internal dependency, use maven dependency tree to identify. and exclude asm dependency.

Note: you can even upgrade these jars to higher versions which in fact support higher versions of ASM(>4.0), which should be fine with GWT 2.7 or 2.8

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to exclude an asm artefact coming from a hibernate validator library so you should be fine excluding any asm artefact in your maven configs for your gwt module.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I had `gwt-servlet.jar` on my classpath during the compilation. If using maven, mark (set the scope) the dependency of `gwt-servlet.jar` as `provided`

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue when I migrated gwt from 2.6.1 to 2.8. Actually this error caused by asm dependency. Some of your server dependency has internal dependency to asm. In my case its cglib. So I changed cglib to cglib-nodep and it worked :-)

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I migrated the asm version to 4.0 and the issue got solved

Comment: How do you migrate? I have packages dependent on asm 3.2, can you provide me a noob link on how to migrate them? Or how to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I wasn't using gwt-servlet.jar and dependencies were referencing old versions of it. I added the latest (matching my gwt-user.jar) as a regular dependency and Maven then knew to only use the latest version. You can check your dependency tree with *mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose*

Answer (score 0):

In my project, a modular GWT application, I had to add a dependency to gwt-dev into the module that started the whole app.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```