# Error switching from gwt 2.7 to 2.8 at super dev mode startup: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am using Eclipse Mars and I am trying to upgrade my projects from GWT 2.7 to 2.8 (Java 8) but I am getting this exception at Super Dev Mode startup:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
...
```

If I try to create a new project with the Web Application option, everything works fine.

I have tried cleaning the workspace projects and the gwt output files, but nothing works.

Startup parameters are: -noprecompile, -port, 9876, -sourceLevel, 1.8, -bindAddress, 0.0.0.0, -launcherDir, /home/..., -logLevel, INFO, -style, OBFUSCATED.

Comment: Take a peek here: [GWT Compilation Error - IncompatibleClassChangeError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176110/gwt-compilation-error-incompatibleclasschangeerror). It could be caused by things hanging around from 2.7

Comment: Yes, it seems it was a conflict with a newer version of htmlunit but in the error logs i didn't receive any detail regarding this. It is ok now, thank you!